# Individual logging in each multiprocessing process

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement logging in a multiprocessing class within Flask but I'm encountering some errors. Is it possible to log individually in the worker class? I just want each worker to log to it's own log file.

Initially I tried with the following, but this caused a `TypeError: Object of type 'TypeError' is not JSON serializable`

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import logging

class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, a, lock, pipe):
        self.a = a
        ...

        self.logger = logging.getLogger('Task Specific Name')
```

So instead I tried without declaring it as a class variable, but as expected it doesn't get passed to the run and TEST2 doesn't get printed.

```
class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, a, lock, pipe):
        self.a = a
        ...

        logger = logging.getLogger('Task Specific Name')
        logger.setLevel...
        logger.setHandlr...
        logger.info('TEST1')

    def run(self):
        logger.info('TEST2')
```

Comment: each logger could have its own StreamHandler instance which outputs to a different file.

Comment: The issue stems from declaring logger at the module level `self.logger = logging.getLogger`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to solve it by creating a new logger in the `run` function as a local variable.

```
def run(self):
    logger = logging.getLogger('name')
    ...
```

I guess it's possible to declare a FileHandler in `__init__` and `run` and point to the same file.